# Restrict overlapping dates of Opportunities with Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, helper

I have an Account and Opportunities for it. These Opportunities have time intervals: Start Date and Close Date. I want to prohibit the creation of Opportunities whose intervals overlap with the intervals of already created Opportunities. How can I do this? Now I'm getting my error from trigger and 'Yes!' from Helper. What is wrong here?

**Here is my Trigger Helper:**

```
public class ApartmentHelper {
public static List<Opportunity> oldRentContracts = [SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, CloseDate, Days__c, Total_cost__c, Net_income__c, AccountId
                                                    FROM Opportunity
                                                    WHERE StageName != 'Closed Won' AND StageName != 'Closed Won'];

public static void handleAfterInsert(List<Opportunity> newRentContracts) {
    for(Opportunity newOpp : newRentContracts){
        for(Opportunity oldOpp : oldRentContracts){

            if((newOpp.AccountId == oldOpp.AccountId) &&
              ((newOpp.Start_Date__c >= oldOpp.Start_Date__c && newOpp.Start_Date__c <= oldOpp.CloseDate) ||
               (newOpp.CloseDate >= oldOpp.Start_Date__c && newOpp.CloseDate <= oldOpp.CloseDate) ||
               (newOpp.Start_Date__c <= oldOpp.Start_Date__c && newOpp.CloseDate >= oldOpp.CloseDate))) {
                   System.debug('No');
            } else{
                System.debug('Yes!'); //I see this
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Trigger:**

```
trigger ApartmentTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {  
  if(Trigger.isBefore){
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        ApartmentHelper.handleAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
        Trigger.new[0].addError('Ouch!'); //But I see this error too
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for answers.

Comment: A nested for loop with `if(rec1.Id == rec2.Id)` is a sign that you should be using a `map` instead. That aside, is there any particular reason why your query is being fed into a static variable? Seems like that would be ripe for selectivity issues.

Comment: Beyond that, this seems like you just need to use some basic debugging skills. Break your big `if` statement down into smaller parts so you can check the individual conditions (i.e. do a debug to see if the account ids match, another debug to peek at the dates for the new opp, another debug to peek at the dates for the old opp, etc...)

Comment: Yes, Thank you) I've just done it. All is fine now. Except the error 'Ouch'. I get it even if all is OK.

Comment: That shouldn't be a surprise. You're adding that error to the first record _every time_ you run that trigger. It's not behind any conditionals. Why do you have that there to begin with?

Comment: I don't remember how to write triggers. Therefore I ask for help. How to display an error under the conditions specified in the helper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking over the code you've provided, I'm not seeing anything jump out as being obviously wrong with the `if` statement for determining overlapping dates.

I have some concerns about a few parts of your code, but nothing that should cause issues with your overlap logic.

### Figuring out what's wrong (if anything)

Times like these generally call for some sanity checking.

The quick-and-dirty way to do this would be to add some debug statements so you can check individual components of your main `if` statement:

- Is newOpp.Id == oldOpp.Id?
- What are the start and close dates for newOpp?
- What are the start and close dates for oldOpp?
- Does your first date check (`newOpp.Start_Date__c >= oldOpp.Start_Date__c && newOpp.Start_Date__c <= oldOpp.CloseDate)`) pass?
- Does your second date check pass?
- Does your third date check pass?

That should give you the information to know whether your logic is wrong, or if the data you're using to test this is wrong (my guess would be that you aren't testing with any Opps pointing to an Account with a non "closed won" Opportunity)

### About your "Ouch" error message

Beyond that, the reason why you're always getting your "Ouch" error message is because you're adding an error to `trigger.new[0]` unconditionally (i.e. every time you run the trigger).

To get an error to surface on a record taking part in a trigger, you just need to `addError()` to the instance of the record in `trigger.new` or `trigger.newMap` (or old/oldMap if you're working with a `Delete` trigger). Lists of SObjects get passed by reference, so `newOpp` in your handler points to the same instance (in-memory) as the corresponding record in `trigger.new`.

Take the `addError()` bit out of your trigger, and use it (in conjunction with `newOpp`) in the `else` block of your handler.

### Additional suggestions

Your static query is not selective, and will eventually cause issues. The place to perform this query is inside of your `handleAfterInsert` method.

You don't need to query *all* Opportunities, just those that are related to the same Account as the Opportunities that your trigger handler is currently working with.

The typical pattern is

```
Set<Id> idsToQuery = new Set<Id>();
for(Opportunity opp :trigger.new){
    idsToQuery.add(opp.AccountId);
}

List<Opportunity> existingOpps = [SELECT Id, <other fields> FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :idsToQuery];
```

The nested loop checking `rec1.Id == rec2.Id` is also a red flag. It'll work, but it's rather "brute force" (and uses a lot of unnecessary CPU time). The general recommendation is to create a map keyed on your target Id so you can get rid of one of the loops.

The bad way:

```
for(Opportunity opp1 :oldOpps){
    for(Opportunity opp2 :newOpps){
        if(opp1.Id == opp2.Id){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

The good way:

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

for(Opportunity opp1 :oldOpps){
    oppsMap.put(opp1.Id, opp);
}

for(Opportunity opp2 :newOpps){
    Opportunity opp1 = oppsMap.get(opp2.Id);

    if(opp1.CloseDate < opp2.CloseDate){
        // interesting things
    }
}
```

Yes, you'll still have two loops, however, the "good" way uses a lot less CPU time.

If, in my example, `oldOpps` contains 100 records, and `newOpps` contains 50...
The "bad" way would loop 100 * 50 = 5000 times
The "good" way would loop 100 + 50 = 150 times

The "bad" way loops over 33x more than the "good" way, even for these modest numbers.

To do what you want to do, you'll probably want to create a `Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>` to store the list of Opportunities that are related to a given Account Id. You could then know exactly which Opps are related to the same account your current "newOpp" is related to. You'll still need the nested loop (because you need to compare against *all* of the Opps related to your newOpp's Account), but the amount of records you work with in your inner loop will generally be a lot less than "all of them".

You'll need to make some changes to my above example to get that working, but the result should be code that's more efficient and easier to debug/maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Derek, I remembered how to do this. Here is my solution:

```
public static void handleAfterInsert(List<Opportunity> newRentContracts, Set<Id> idsToQuery) {
    List<Opportunity> oldRentContracts = [SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, CloseDate, AccountId
                                          FROM Opportunity
                                          WHERE StageName != 'Closed Won' AND StageName != 'Closed Won' AND AccountId IN : idsToQuery];

    for(Opportunity newOpp : newRentContracts){
        for(Opportunity oldOpp : oldRentContracts){

            if((newOpp.Start_Date__c >= oldOpp.Start_Date__c && newOpp.Start_Date__c <= oldOpp.CloseDate) ||
               (newOpp.CloseDate >= oldOpp.Start_Date__c && newOpp.CloseDate <= oldOpp.CloseDate) ||
               (newOpp.Start_Date__c <= oldOpp.Start_Date__c && newOpp.CloseDate >= oldOpp.CloseDate)) {
                   newOpp.addError('Dates from ' + oldOpp.Start_Date__c + ' to ' + oldOpp.CloseDate + ' for this apartment are occupied! Please select a free date.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Trigger:

```
Set<Id> idsToQuery = new Set<Id>();

if(Trigger.isBefore){
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){

        for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){
            idsToQuery.add(opp.AccountId);
        }
        Helper.handleAfterInsert(Trigger.new, idsToQuery);
    }
}
```